# C++ - How can I Call Static Functions from Everywhere, that Alter its Private Variables?

Tags: c++, class, static

For example, I have a class that stores the application name:

```
class Storage {
public:
    static char* getName();
private:
    char* name;
}
```

I want to access it from, for example, in the main() function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

char* name;

Storage s;
name = s.getName();
cout << name << endl;

return 0;
}
```

As you know, I can't access it, because a static method needs to use a static variable. When I tried to make "name" private static, I get linker errors. I don't want to declare a public static variable, because I want to encapsulate it. I want to make it static, because I want to call the method from every part of the code.

Consider, that program has a global name and it must be encapsulated, and you want to reach the name from every part of the code. What should you do? In Java, private static variables were legal. But in C++, it's very confusing.

Comment: The statement "static method needs to use a static variable" makes no sense. I can write a static method that doesn't need to use any variable, static or otherwise. And as far as Java goes, Java's class static variables work exactly the same as they do in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is declared in header file you have to define static members in some .cpp file simillary to functions:

```
char* Storage::name;
```

Btw your code may compile now, but you have to assign some value to 'name' before reading it.

Comment: It works! One more question. Using private statics legal? Because someone said using it is against C++ specification.

Comment: Yes, It's okay if you initialize them properly.